# get column name by mysql intersect equivalent

Tags: mysql

I have the following structure for a table what i want is MySQL query equivalent to this query:

```
 SELECT column_name
    FROM information_schema.columns
    WHERE table_name = 'table_name'
        AND company = '77'
        AND columns IS NOT NULL OR columns IS NOT = 0
    INTERSECT
    SELECT column_name
    FROM information_schema.columns
    WHERE table_name = 'table_name'
        AND company = '799'
        AND columns IS NOT NULL OR columns IS NOT = 0
    INTERSECT
    SELECT column_name
    FROM information_schema.columns
    WHERE table_name = 'table_name'
        AND company = '700'
        AND columns IS NOT NULL OR columns IS NOT = 0
    INTERSECT
    SELECT column_name
    FROM information_schema.columns
    WHERE table_name = 'table_name'
        AND company = '788'
        AND columns IS NOT NULL OR columns IS NOT = 0
```

> calling_numb
>   |called_num|cell_id|calling_loc|called_loc|company|cell_type|called_reg
>   |c_site
>
> +937779832423|+93799234323|C8435|   NULL    | NULL     | 77    | Nokia   | 44       |443543
>
> +937883432424|+93700335234|S6700| 4         |  9       | 788   | 435341  | NULL     | NULL
>
> +937999343324|+93788324234|W580 | Ghazni    |   Herat  | 799   | Kabul   | NULL     | NULL
>
> +937003556322|+93788342343|K860 | 01        |   NULL   | 700   | NULL    | NULL     | 6823
>
> +937778342453|+93700453423|L900 | 05        | 12       | 77    | Samsung | NULL     | NULL
>
> +937994354356|+93789345435|K334 | Ghazni    | Herat    | 799   | Nokia   | NULL     | 3345
>
> +937004353455|+93799033453|S6790| NULL      | NULL     | 700   | NULL    | xYZ      |34543

Comment: no just those numbers are for testing not real ones

Comment: Could you explain what you need? You are querying information_schema and where is company condition?

Comment: Sorry i forgot some portion of query i updated now please check if its clear for u

Comment: I dont understand your query.

Comment: my aim is to to take table columns name where company field of table is equal to 77 but also those fields that are not null and not 0 for company = 77 and then for other company and intersect them together

Comment: But from information_schema.columns table? Where did you get that?

Comment: FYI, There is no `INTERSECT` in MySQL. You will have join the tables to get the matching rows (that's what intersect is all about). I don't understand from where you are getting that `company` column cause `information_schema.columns` table have no such column.

Comment: yeah the main problem for me is this because when we take from meta data how can we check one of column value in condition?

Comment: yeah i mentioned that for finding mysql intersect alternate, join is one of them but by join how can i do that purpose, i get these data from different telecome companies about different SIM belonged to them along them i store the code of company in table